# Changing size of widget without changing main window size in QT

Tags: qt, opengl

I have a QT application, in that, Mainwindow contains two Opengl widgets (i.e. two Opengl display windows in main window). One Opengl window is for editing and other one for showing result. I have attached the image of application. I want to re-size each Opengl window independently i.e. I don't want to change the size of Mainwindow when I change any of openGl window. Please tell me how to do this?[image]

Comment: How are you creating/positioning the windows currently - is this based on a Qt layout ?

Comment: yes it is based on QT layout

Answer (score 1):

I think in order to be successful you'll have re-evaluate your layout all together from the top and think about how the user is going to interact with the different areas.

While you do that you should look at [QDockWidget](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtwidgets/qdockwidget.html) and [QSplitter](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtwidgets/qsplitter.html) to allow your user to move and resize the areas you want without resizing your main window. It will also allow users to move areas around if they want in it a different part of your application.

Then use `QLayout` objects within each area to get the desired layout of each dockable/split area.